# how can I filter the list if it is in another component?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

When decomposing the project, there was a problem with filtering the list, since the filter is in header-component, and the list is displayed in main, I use vuex in vue, but I don't understand how to implement it.

```
state: {
 dataDB: null,
 searchValue:''
},
 getters: {
 dataDB: state => state.dataDB,
 filterData (state, searchValue) {
   if (state.dataDB) {
     return state.dataDB
     .filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase()
     .includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()))
   }
 }
 }
```

```
getters: {
 dataDB: state => state.dataDB,
 filterData: (state) => (searchValue) => {
   return state.dataDB
   .filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase()
   .includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()))
 }
},
search component
<input type="search" v-model="searchValue">
 <button @click="search" </button>
   methods: {
 search() {
   const filteredData = this.$store.getters.filterData(this.searchValue);
   this.$store.commit('setData', filteredData);
 }
}
```

but with this code, I always get a truncated array (if I enter r - 20 elements and with each time less and less)